# Is there any way to get projection without creating GeoPoint?

Tags: android, performance, overlay, draw

In my application i have multiply overlays over the map.

In each overlay's `draw()` method i draw shape using points from list.

> ```
>       final int listSize = list.size();
>             for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
>                 mMapView.getProjection().toPixels(
>                         new GeoPoint((int) (list.get(i).getPNT_LATITUDE() * 1e6), (int) (list.get(i).getPNT_LONGITUDE() * 1e6)), point);
> ```

As you can see, i have to create `GeoPoint` object each cycle to get pixel projection.
I can't creat single object and use it every time, because `GeoPoint` has no "set" methods.

Is there any way to get projection without creating GeoPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, unfortunately not. i would almost pay for this functionality ;)
many map things around GeoPoints and the Projection are very buggy and the classes are all final and no source code to be found

if your coordinates somehow repeat themselves, you could store the geopoint.